# cardinality proof: prove that for any set $A, \ 2^{|A|} \neq |\mathbb{N}|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Prove: for any set $A, \ 2^{|A|} \neq \aleph _{0}$

as $\aleph_{0} = |\mathbb{N}|$.

**my attempt:**

Suppose by contradiction that there exist a set $A$ such that $2^{|A|} = \aleph_{0}$, which Implies that $|P(A)| = \aleph_{0}$, using [Cantor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem).

meaning, **intuitively** that $ \aleph_{0}  > |A| = \log_{2}(\aleph_{0})$, thus $A$ is finite.

at this point I'm trying to understand why the fact that $A$ is finite means that $P(A)$ also must be finite, which is the core of the argument.

there's no need to prove that $2^{|A|} = \mathfrak{c}$, but only to prove that there exist no set $A$ such that $2^{|A|} = \aleph_{0}$

Comment: Do you know the definition of power set?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'd argue this is not a duplicate, since that result doesn't do the entirety of this question, and the result that $2^{\aleph_0} = c$ is stronger than required (we only need that it's uncountable, not that it's a particular other cardinality).

Comment: The concept of $\log_2$ for infinite cardinals, in any standard sense, doesn't make any sense; the power-set operation isn't (necessarily) one-to-one on cardinalities.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki this is why I highlighted the word "intuitively"  - which suggests that isn't a formal argument but only an intuition, as a part of the attempt to prove why there isn't exist a set which maintains this properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is finite, with $|A| = n$, then $|P(A)| = 2^{|A|} = 2^{n} < \aleph_{0}$ which is a contradiction to the definition of $\aleph_{0}$.

Comment: Therefore $|\mathcal{P}(A)|>|A|\ge\aleph_0$.

Comment: @J.G. Those inequalities you’ve mentioned seem off.

Comment: They follow once you've precluded finite $|A|$, completing a proof by contradiction (relative to your old edit).

Comment: You’re correct on that end. The other part of the question is realizing $\aleph_{0}$ is the smallest infinite cardinal.

Comment: Yeah, at some point you have to use that or prove it.

Answer (score 0):

$|2^{|A|}-|\mathbb{N}|| \geq 2^{|A|}-|\mathbb{N}|$,

Now, $|A|<2^{|A|}$,

$2^{|A|}-|\mathbb{N}|>|A|-|\mathbb{N}|$,

If $2^{|A|} =|\mathbb{N}|$, then
$|\mathbb{N}|>|A|$, meaning A is finite, so its power set will also be finite, contradicting the assumption.
As,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPMpg.png,)

As long as $S$ is finite, series is convergent. Therefore, proved

**Another proof**,

Using 2^|A|=|N| as hypothesis,
By Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem, 2^|A|=|N|

iff ,**2^|A|>=|N| and 2^|A|<=|N|**,

by Cantor's theorem, |A|<2^|A|

(|A|>=|N| or |A|<=|N|) and |A|<|N|,

(|A|>=|N| and |A|<|N|) or (|A|<=|N|and |A|<|N|),

the first curly bracket is a contradiction and second bracket refers A as finite set which is again an absurdity, so by logical disjuction, hypothesis of 2^|A|=|N| is false.

Comment: What is $2^{|A|}-|\Bbb N|$?

Comment: 2^|A|!=|N|; 2^|A|−|N|!=0, so used this as hypothesis.

Comment: Cardinal subtraction is not well defined.

Comment: please check the second proof